# iDrive backup for Mac failing

Tags: macos, backup, software-recommendation

I got a message from my Mac IDrive app that there has been no backup for four days. The message says the most common cause is the Mac being turned off, but my Mac is always on and connected.  IDrive has been working fine for months.

IDrive support suggested that I [upgrade to version 3.5.1.5](https://www.idrive.com/release-info) but that's what I have, and they haven't responded further. There's no clue in the logs; it just says "Backup operation failed" at the end after listing files for backup.  I Have paid for a years service.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this other than requesting another support ticket?

Comment: Seeing that you *paid* for this, I would stay on top of the issue with the developer of the app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: My original question has been edited out: "Anyone else see this recently? Is there a known cause and solution?"  I generally assume I'm not the only one having a particular problem, and that someone has had the same problem and perhaps found a solution. The app developer is not responding. Is there a better place in Stack to ask customer support questions?

Comment: @vonlost We are not a good place for customer support. We are a place for specific answers to specific questions. I’ll assume you need a software suggestion since I can’t help with troubleshooting your vendor. I know one that does support very well and another you can’t avoid being able to troubleshoot as it requires expert skills to even set up.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep on the vendor to explain how to debug this sync failure.

If they don’t make you happy, the team that make a ARQ software has a history of resolving issues for their clients (in my circle of Mac admins and consultants).

- https://www.arqbackup.com/

If you’re technical and prefer command line, I can’t recommend rsync.net highly enough either. Their price point is attractive as is the detailed logging capabilities for troubleshooting - if you can set it up, you can troubleshoot it easily. Go for arq if ease of setup is your preference.

- https://rsync.net/products/attic.html

Comment: BackBlaze are the usual cloud backup people.

Answer (score 0):

iDrive customer support is indeed lousy and the interface is confusing—but they are the only option I've been able to find for backing up multiple computers.

I have sometimes had luck with resolving backup failures by forcing verification of the backup set under settings.